# List Item dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code to display dropdown, but looks both name and value pairs are coming same when it displayed in dropdown.

aspx.cs:

```
DropDownList dp = new DropDownList();
dp.ID = ToString();

dp.Items.Add(new ListItem("test1", "This is test1"));
dp.Items.Add(new ListItem("test2", "This is test2"));

Script.DataSource = dp.Items;
Script.DataBind();
```

aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Script" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ScriptSelected" AutoPostBack="true">

</asp:DropDownList>
```

When I debug came to know that both name and value are coming same, like below

```
<select name="Script" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;Script\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="Script">
<option value="test1">test1</option>
<option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
```

but need like below

```
<select name="Script" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;Script\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="Script">
<option value="test1">This is test1</option>
<option value="test2">This is test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do something like "dropDown.DataTextField = "Key";", look here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602174/bind-list-to-dropdownlist-what-to-do-with-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify both the DataValueField and the DataTextField for your control.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Script" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ScriptSelected" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or, if you want to do it server side,

```
DropDownList dp = new DropDownList();
dp.ID = ToString();
dp.DataTextField = "Text";
dp.DataValueField = "Value";

dp.Items.Add(new ListItem("test1", "This is test1"));
dp.Items.Add(new ListItem("test2", "This is test2"));

Script.DataSource = dp.Items;
Script.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response, Its working as expected